# VB.Net Datatable Select MID function

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, datatable, datarow

I'm trying to extract all rows from a datatable where "CODE" follows the pattern "Z##A". I tried the following to no avail:

```
Dim floods() As DataRow = arqTable.Select("mid(code,1,1)='Z' and isnumeric(mid(code,2,2)) and mid(code,4,1)='A'")
```

An error returned

> "The expression contains undefined
>   function call mid()."

I **could** go through the rows using a `FOR EACH` loop but I'm just curious if there is a way to simply use the datatable select function.

*Edit: BTW, using "code like 'Z%A'" is not going to work as I'm specifically looking for Z[number][number]A and not ones with Z[letter][letter]A.

Comment: what's your back end?  you need to use that syntax.  for sql server, check out substring.

Comment: Awesome, substring works! Now isnumeric throws an undefined function

Comment: because it's undefined syntax on your back end.  try running your select statement on your back end.  if it doesn't work there, it won't work after being sent by your code.

Comment: Problem is, I don't know what back end the .net framework datatable select statement is using

Comment: @Beth I think you're confused. DataTables don't have a backend. For example the arqTable could have been populated with the DataTable.Add() method

Comment: You guys are right- I thought he was sending the select statement to a server.  From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx, looks like you can try convert, or maybe IIF

Comment: Correct Conrad Frix, it was populated with .Add()s

Comment: @Beth, that MSDN article doesn't seem to show how to find an alphanumeric wildcard [0-9] doesn't work

Comment: It shows the syntax you're looking for, try using convert(code,int) or iif(isnumeric(code),true,false).  It doesn't explain the syntax limitations of the expression in the IIF function.

Comment: Figured it out!  Dim floods() As DataRow = arqTable.Select("code LIKE 'Z%' and code like '%A' AND substring(code,2,2)>0")

Comment: @brettville that will fail for codes like "ZAAA"

Comment: @Conrad, yes you're correct about it failing when the middle 2 characters are not numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works

```
Dim r1() As DataRow = dt.Select("code LIKE 'Z%' and code LIKE '%A' and substring(code, 2, 1) >=  '0'  and substring(code, 2, 1) <= '9' and substring(code, 3, 1) >= '0' AND substring(code, 3, 1) <= '9' and len(code) =  4 ")
```

If your at all concerned about efficiency check out this quick example as a point of interest from a performance perspective. (paste into a console application).

Results...

```
1000 RECORDS...
SELECT: 00:00:00.0050357 matches 141
VBLIKE: 00:00:00.0021198 matches 141 - %250.0
VBRAW: 00:00:00.0007444 matches 141 - Infinity
CREGEX: 00:00:00.0014745 matches 141 - %500.0

10000 RECORDS...
SELECT: 00:00:00.0530854 matches 1430
VBLIKE: 00:00:00.0280535 matches 1430 - %189.3
VBRAW: 00:00:00.0067957 matches 1430 - %883.3
CREGEX: 00:00:00.0026389 matches 1430 - %2650.0

100000 RECORDS...
SELECT: 00:00:00.6141986 matches 13929
VBLIKE: 00:00:00.1773157 matches 13929 - %346.9
VBRAW: 00:00:00.0699633 matches 13929 - %889.9
CREGEX: 00:00:00.0271444 matches 13929 - %2274.1

1000000 RECORDS...
SELECT: 00:00:06.2316807 matches 138987
VBLIKE: 00:00:01.7882370 matches 138987 - %348.5
VBRAW: 00:00:00.7093068 matches 138987 - %878.8
CREGEX: 00:00:00.2714249 matches 138987 - %2299.3
```

Code

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Public RegEx_Code As New Regex("^Z[0-9][0-9]A$", RegexOptions.Compiled)

    Sub Main()
        Dim trials() As Integer = {1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000} 'data sizes to test
        For Each recCnt As Integer In trials
            'build test data that is sort of similar.
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add("code", GetType(String))
            For iQ As Integer = 0 To recCnt - 1
                dt.Rows.Add(If(iQ Mod 4 = 0, "Z", "X") & Chr(Int(Rnd() * 15) + 48) & Chr(Int(Rnd() * 12) + 48) & If(iQ Mod 2 = 0, "A", "Y"))
            Next

            'test SELECT
            Dim sw1 As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew
            Dim r1() As DataRow = dt.Select("code LIKE 'Z%' and code LIKE '%A' and substring(code, 2, 1) >=  '0'  and substring(code, 2, 1) <= '9' and substring(code, 3, 1) >= '0' AND substring(code, 3, 1) <= '9' and len(code) =  4 ")
            sw1.Stop()

            'test VB built in LIKE
            Dim sw2 As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew
            Dim r2 As New List(Of DataRow)(recCnt \ 20)
            Dim rInd2 As Integer = dt.Columns("code").Ordinal
            For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
                If CStr(r(rInd2)) Like "Z##A" Then
                    r2.Add(r)
                End If
            Next
            r2.TrimExcess()
            sw2.Stop()

            Dim sw3 As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew
            Dim r3 As New List(Of DataRow)(recCnt \ 20)
            Dim rInd3 As Integer = dt.Columns("code").Ordinal
            For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
                Dim value As String = CStr(r(rInd3))
                If value.Length = 4 AndAlso IsNumeric(value.Substring(1, 1)) AndAlso IsNumeric(value.Substring(2, 1)) AndAlso value.StartsWith("Z") AndAlso value.EndsWith("A") Then
                    r3.Add(r)
                End If
            Next
            r3.TrimExcess()
            sw3.Stop()

            'test Compiled Regular Expression.
            Dim sw4 As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew
            Dim r4 As New List(Of DataRow)(recCnt \ 20)
            Dim rInd4 As Integer = dt.Columns("code").Ordinal
            For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
                If RegEx_Code.IsMatch(CStr(r(rInd4))) Then
                    r4.Add(r)
                End If
            Next
            r4.TrimExcess()
            sw4.Stop()
            Console.WriteLine(recCnt & " RECORDS...")
            Console.WriteLine("SELECT: " & sw1.Elapsed.ToString & " matches " & r1.Length)
            Console.WriteLine("VBLIKE: " & sw2.Elapsed.ToString & " matches " & r2.Count & " - " & CDbl(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds / sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString("%0.0"))
            Console.WriteLine("VBRAW: " & sw3.Elapsed.ToString & " matches " & r3.Count & " - " & CDbl(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds / sw3.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString("%0.0"))
            Console.WriteLine("CREGEX: " & sw4.Elapsed.ToString & " matches " & r3.Count & " - " & CDbl(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds / sw4.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString("%0.0"))
            Console.WriteLine()

        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
arqTable.Select("code LIKE 'Z%' and code LIKE '%A' and substring(code, 2, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' and substring(code, 3, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'")
```

Comment: :( The expression contains unsupported operator 'Between'.

Comment: If between isn't supported, you can always use >= and <=

Comment: Would that cause an error when the characters aren't numerical?

Answer (score 0):

Hi
you can use solution suggested by **Mircea Dogaru**

as 
arqTable.Select("code LIKE 'Z%' and code LIKE '%A' and substring(code, 2, 1) BETWEEN '0' 
AND '9' and substring(code, 3, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'")

with one more condition 
length(code) = 4

as follow--

```
arqTable.Select("code LIKE 'Z%' and code LIKE '%A' and substring(code, 2, 1) BETWEEN 
'0' AND '9' and substring(code, 3, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' and length(code) =  4 ")
```

Comment: Thanks but please see the comments along with Mircea's suggestion, the between operator isn't supported

Comment: i wanted to tell you about this lenth condition..
what you have to put in your code